# TypeError('list indices must be integers, not str',) with get() method in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to convert JSON files to CSV using below code. The PARENT_ID and PARENT_TYPE fields can be NULL most of the times. If I use result["parent"]["id"] it returns KeyError. That's why I thought of using get() to return whatever value they hold. But I am getting **TypeError('list indices must be integers, not str',)** for these fields. Can anyone suggest any workaround? 
Thanks in advance!

> "parent" is a list within "result" dict.

```
my_dict_list =[]
try:
    for f in os.listdir(file_dir):
        if f.endswith('.json') and f.startswith('folders_'):
            file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, f)
            data = open(file_path, 'r')
            for line in data:
                my_dict = {}
                parsed_data = json.loads(line)
                my_dict["REQUEST_ID"] = parsed_data["requestId"]
                my_dict["SUCCESS"] = parsed_data["success"]
                for result in parsed_data["result"]:
                    my_dict["NAME"] = result["name"]
                    my_dict["DESCRIPTION"] = result["description"]
                    my_dict["FOLDER_ID"] = result["folderId"]["id"]
                    my_dict["FOLDER_ID_TYPE"] = result["folderId"]["type"]
                    my_dict["FOLDER_TYPE"] = result["folderType"]
                    my_dict["PARENT_ID"] = result.get(["parent"]["id"])
                    my_dict["PARENT_TYPE"] = result.get(["parent"]["type"])
```

Comment: as a tip try using continue statement on your if conditions, it will help your code indentation.

Comment: is `result['parent']` a list of objects? Can you post the json/structure of json please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are trying to access the member "id" from a list with the string "parent" in the following line:

```
my_dict["PARENT_ID"] = result.get(["parent"]["id"])
```

You have to check if the result dict contains the key "parent".
The [get method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) of your result dict can be used for this.

It returns *None* if the dict does not contain the key "parent".
Otherwise use the get method and try to get the *id* of the parent

Your code has to be

```
my_dict["PARENT_ID"] = result["parent"].get("id") if result.get("parent") else None
```